# How to remove asset which was in layout on particular page in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have this asset set in `layout.phtml` globally on my website:

```
$this->InlineScript()
    ->offsetSetFile(4, $this->basePath('crm-assets/js/permissions.js'))
```

How to remove this file on particular page on the website?

Is there any methods for this:
`$this->InlineScript()->unset(4)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view helper inherits from `Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\AbstractStandalone` which implements `ArrayObject` and proxies <s>all</s> most calls to a 'collection' that it manages.

Normally you could use the `unset()` function

```
$helper = $this->inlineScript();
unset($helper->someKey}
```

However as the key is a `integer` you will need to call `offsetUnset()` from the internal container.

```
$helper->getContainer()->offsetUnset(4);
```